# Elasticsearch delimited payload token filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use [delimited_payload_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-delimited-payload-tokenfilter.htm) for text field but no luck

heres my requests :

```
PUT /myIndex
{
"settings": {
    "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
            "kuku" : {
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter" : ["delimited_payload_filter"]
            }
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
   "calls" : {
      "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "kuku"
            }
       }
     }
 }
}
```

}

Then I add the following doc:

```
PUT /myIndex/calls/1
{
    "text" : "the|1 quick|2 fox|3"
}
```

I expect that if I will do the following query I will get a hit but i didnt.

```
GET /myIndex/calls/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
             "text": "quick fox"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change tokenizer to something other than "standard" like "whitespace". The "standard" is tokenizing the text and stripping the "|" delimiter before the delimited_payload filter has a chance to work on it.